# Why is the constructor undefined?

Tags: java, enums, bukkit, enum-class

Even though I'm working with Bukkit, this is a Java problem;

I don't know, why Java says the constructor is undefined, since it is defined

```
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.EntityCow;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.EntityInsentient;

public enum Pets
{
    COW("Cow", 92, EntityType.COW, EntityCow.class, Pets.class);

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private EntityType et;
    private Class<? extends EntityInsentient> nmsClass;
    private Class<? extends EntityInsentient> customClass;

    Pets(String name, int id, EntityType et, Class<? extends EntityInsentient> nmsClass, Class<? extends EntityInsentient> customClass)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.et = et;
        this.nmsClass = nmsClass;
        this.customClass = customClass;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getID()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public EntityType getET()
    {
        return et;
    }
    public Class<? extends EntityInsentient> getNMSClass()
    {
        return nmsClass;
    }
    public Class<? extends EntityInsentient> getCustomClass()
    {
        return customClass;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how tho solve this, because I looked around and found nothing other than this syntax and it seems like all the conversations regarding topics like this are at least 5 years old and very vague.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor of your enum `Pets` expects 5 parameters:

```
 Pets(String name, int id, EntityType et,
      Class<? extends EntityInsentient> nmsClass,
      Class<? extends EntityInsentient> customClass)
```

When you declare the constant `COW` you are using this constructor:

```
COW("Cow", 92, EntityType.COW, EntityCow.class, Pets.class);
```

Note that the 5th parameter, `Pets.class`, does not conform to what the constructor expects, because enum `Pets` does not extend or implement `EntityInsentient`.

There are several ways to solve this, but which one you should use depends on the rest of your program and what you're trying to achieve:

- You could change the constructor and the field `customClass`, remove the bound `extends EntityInsentient`.
- You could make the enum implement `EntityInsentient` (`public enum Pets implements EntityInsentient`); this will only work if that is an interface (enums cannot extend classes).